# Where put auxiliary files used by my DLL with good practices

Tags: c++, r, c, dll

I'm developing a C DLL/so to be used in windows and Linux. It will have to open and use some files text and binaries (not DLLs/so). Where should I place these files used by the DLL/so ?

I thought to place them in windows system32 and in the DLL use the absolute path path to find them but it won't work in linux (with so file in /usr/lib folder).

The files are a R script and a binary model used by the R script.

Which would be an ideal place with good practices? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linux: /usr/local/lib

Windows: Windows/System32

Dlls are found by name (without absolute path).

Comment: I'm not asking where tu put the dlls but the auxiliary files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On windows I would say put the auxiliary files somewhere under either Program Files or users\all users\AppData or users<current user>\AppData. In either case use the known folder API to get the actual path being used. Just because your 'program' is a DLL does not mean you can't make up a product name.

Comment: I don't know that "know folder API" is valid also for linux or only for windows? Thanks